# How do I set a previously 'disabled' button in an html, to 'enabled', once a progress bar is at 100%?

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently trying to enable a disabled button, once a certain action is complete. In this case, a progress bar reaching 100%. My button looks like this:

```js
var i;
function move() {
  if (i == 0) {
    i = 1;
    var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
    var width = 10;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 100);
    function frame() {
      if (width >= 100) {
        clearInterval(id);
        i = 0;
      } else {
        width++;
        elem.style.width = width + "%";
        elem.innerHTML = width  + "%";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="myProgress">
    <div id="myBar">0%</div>
  </div>
  
  <br><button onclick="move()">Run Experiment</button><br>

<button disabled id="btn1" onclick="location.href='https://google.com'" type="button">
  Go to Google</button>
```

I'm thinking that there must be a possibility to have some sort of if else condition in the button itself. Ideally, I could do this in the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already have a working conditional to stop the progress bar updates when 100% is reached. This is the place where you can activate the button. You can wrap that code to another function.

```js
var i = 0;

function move() {
  if (i == 0) {
    i = 1;
    var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
    var width = 10;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 100);
    function frame() {
      if (width >= 100) {
      
        // Enable the button when the progres is 100%
        var button = document.getElementById("btn1");
        button.disabled = false;
        button.innerHTML = "enabled Button";
        
        clearInterval(id);
        i = 0;
      } else {
        width++;
        elem.style.width = width + "%";
        elem.innerHTML = width  + "%";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<button disabled id="btn1" type="button">disabled Button</button>

<div id="myProgress">
  <div id="myBar">0%</div>
</div>
  
<br><button onclick="move()">Run Experiment</button><br>
```

Comment: this solves my problem! However, when the progress bar runs through again, the button is not greyed out anymore, so the value seems to be set as ```button.disabled = false```. Is there a way to always make it dependent on whether the progress bar is at 100%? If I want to run my experiment again for example.

Comment: It would also work for me if there is an option to reset the whole window...

Comment: Just disable the button again with `button.disabled = true;` when you press the "run experiment" button.

Answer (score 2):

I reduced timer to 10 ms to make snippet more representative

```js
function move() {
  var i=0;
  if (i == 0) {
    i = 1;
    var elem = document.getElementById("myBar");
    var width = 10;
    var id = setInterval(frame, 10);
    function frame() {
      if (width >= 100) {
        clearInterval(id);
        i = 0;
        document.getElementById("btn1").disabled = false;
      } else {
        width++;
        elem.style.width = width + "%";
        elem.innerHTML = width  + "%";
      }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="myProgress">
    <div id="myBar">0%</div>
  </div>
  
  <br><button onclick="move()">Run Experiment</button><br>
  
  <button disabled="enabled" id="btn1" onclick="location.href='https://google.com'" type="button">
  Go to Google</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var progressContainer=document.getElementById("myProgress");
var progress = document.getElementById("myBar");
var googleBtn =document.getElementById("btn1");
var loading = false;

function move() { 
  if(loading)return;
  loading =true;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 50);
  var width =parseInt(progress.offsetWidth /progressContainer.offsetWidth);
  
  function frame() {
    if (width >= 100) {
      clearInterval(id);
      googleBtn.disabled = false;
      loading = false;
      return;
    } 
    width++;
    progress.style.width = width + "%";
    progress.innerHTML = width  + "%";
 }
 
}
```

```css
#myProgress{
  width:200px;
  height:20px;
  border:1px solid black;
  background-color:#bbb;
}
#myBar{
  width:0px;
  background-color:green;
}
```

```html
<div id="myProgress">
    <div id="myBar">0%</div>
  </div>
  
  <br><button onclick="move()">Run Experiment</button><br>
  
  <button disabled="enabled" id="btn1" onclick="location.href='https://google.com'" type="button">
  Go to Google</button>
```